# Finding internal angles of polygon

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have some **lines** that their intersection describes a polygon, like this:

[image: main polygon]

I know the order of the lines, and their equations.

To find the internal angles, I found each lines orientations. But I've got confused as subtracting two lines orientation would give two different angles, even if I do it in the order of polygon's sides.

For example, in the following image, if I just subtract the orientation of the lines, I would get any of the following angles:

[image: defect 1]

What made me more confused, is when the polygon is not convex, I will have angles greater than 180, and using my approach I don't get the correct angle at all:

[image: defect 2]

And I found out that this way of approaching the problem is wrong.

So, What is the best way of finding the internal angles using **just the lines**? I know for a convex polygon, I may find vectors and then find the angle between them, but even for P6 in my example the vector approach fails.

Anyway, I prefer a method that won't include a conditional case for solving that concavity problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know direction of polygon traversal (e.g. clockwise)?

Comment: And how your lines are described?

Comment: Yes, I know the direction, I have the set of lines in clockwise order. The lines are described with two points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With ordered lines it is possible to find points of intersection (polygon vertexes) in clockwise order. Then you can calculate internal angles:

```
Angle[i] =  Pi + ArcTan2(V[i] x V[i+1], V[i] * V[i+1])
```

(crossproduct and dotproduct of incoming and outgoing vectors for every vertex)

or

```
Angle[i] = Pi + ArcTan2( dx_in*dy_out-dx_out*dy_in, dx_in*dx_out+dy_in*dy_out2 )
```

Note: change plus sign after `Pi` to minus for anti-clockwise direction.

Edit:

Note that crossproduct and dotproduct are scalars, not vectors.

Example for your data:

```
dx1 = 5; dy1 = -15; dx2 = -15; dy2 = 5

Angle = Pi + ArcTan2(5*5-15*15, -5*15-5*15) = Pi - 2.11 radians ~ 59 degrees
```

Example for vectors:

```
(0,-1) (1,0) (L-curve)

Angle = Pi + ArcTan2(1, 0) =  270 degrees
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. There's something I don't get about the arguments of ArcTan2, if the second argument is dotproduct, how is it possible to take ArcTan2 with a number and a vector? If it's possible, please consider illustrating the calculations with these two vectors: V[i]=(5,-15) and V[i+1]=(-15,5). Thanks again.

Comment: Read [the wiki on the crossproduct](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product). A cross product returns a **vector**, perpendicular to the plane the polygon lies in. Because |<sub>1</sub>×<sub>2</sub>| = |<sub>1</sub>||<sub>2</sub>|sin() and <sub>1</sub>·<sub>2</sub> = |<sub>1</sub>||<sub>2</sub>|cos(), and since tan() ≡ sin()/cos(), taking the arctangent of |cross|/dot finds the angle (but notice the *magnitude* signs). Your method is correct, but your understanding of it is incomplete.

Comment: More importantly, your method only applies to the 2D case, and will require a coordinate transformation for polygons defined in 3D, which I guarantee will be messy. A more general approach is thus to use the magnitude of the cross product, instead of just the `z`-component of the resultant vector (which is what your method implicitly does).